# I want to trigger a exe and also msi using NSIS in Specific order

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to create a one click installer using NSIS. i have more than one exe and msi to execute in order. using script how can i line up for... Can NSIS have the option to run the msi files. help me thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) has a page showing [how to embed installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers) that you should read.

In short: putting the third-party installers in a directory and [ExecWait](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.4) are your friends.

Comment: @SujeethDamodharan: read the 2nd link I have provided. It shows that the command to invoke is `ExecWait '"msiexec" /i'`

Comment: Wow its working Seki :):) thanks a lot... one more help i want to see my service in services what can i do so.. am new in NSIS scripting help me... thanks